# How to repeat a function 3 times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating this function to test if a user input(as a guess) is correct or not.

```
def check_guess():
   letter = "d"
   guess = input("What is your guess: ")
   if guess.isalpha() == False:
       print("This is invalid")
   elif guess.lower() > letter:
       print("This too high")
   elif guess.lower() < letter:
       print("this is too low")
   else:
       print("that is correct")

check_guess()
```

So I created this code, and it works no problem. However, I am now tasked with having to give the user 3 attempts. If the user gets the correct answer, then the "that is correct" will be printed and the game ends. But if they fail on all 3 attempts, then it's something like "Gameover".

How do I create/duplicate the code to make it able to do that?

Comment: Use a `while` loop..

Answer (score 3):

Use a `for` loop and its `else` clause. The `else` clause of a loop only runs if you didn't break out of the loop.

Start by having your function return a value to indicate whether the user guessed correctly or not. Otherwise it'll be very difficult to interact with it:

```
def check_guess():
    letter = "d"
    guess = input("What is your guess: ")
    if not guess.isalpha():
        print("This is invalid")
        return False
    guess = guess.lower()
    if guess == letter:
        print("that is correct")
        return True
    if guess > letter:
        print("This too high")
    else:
        print("this is too low")
    return False
```

Now you can call the function exactly three times, or until the user guesses correctly, whichever comes first:

```
for _ in range(3):
    if check_guess():
        break
else:
    print('you failed')
```

When `check_guess` returns `True` to indicate success, we `break` out of the loop, ensuring that the `else` clause is *not* triggered. If the three iterations complete and the user never made a correct guess, the clause is triggered.

Answer (score 2):

```
def check_guess():
   letter = "d"
   guess = input("What is your guess: ")
   if guess.isalpha() == False:
       print("This is invalid")
       return False
   elif guess.lower() > letter:
       print("This too high")
       return False
   elif guess.lower() < letter:
       print("this is too low")
       return False
   else:
       print("that is correct")
       return True

for i in range(0,3):
     status = check_guess()
     If status:
         print(“success”)
         break
else:
     print(“fail”)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return if the user was right, and then if not increment a counter. Something like this should work:

```
count = 0
while count < 3:
    if check_guess():
        # he's right
        break
    else:
        # he's wrong
        count += 1
if count >= 3:
    print("You lose !")
else:
    print("You win !")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way:

```
def check_guess():
    status = False
    letter = "d"
    guess = input("What is your guess: ")
    if guess.isalpha() == False:
        print("This is invalid")
    elif guess.lower() > letter:
        print("This too high")
    elif guess.lower() < letter:
        print("this is too low")
    else:
        print("that is correct")
        status = True
    return status

for i in range(3):
    status = check_guess()
    if status:
        break
else:
    print "Gameover"
```

Comment: I did, it works for me. what error does it give to you?

Comment: You might consider always setting the status to False in the function. What's the point of passing it in conceptually?

Answer (score -2):

```
 c=0
 def check_guess():
 letter = "d"
 guess = input("What is your guess: ")
 if guess.isalpha() == False:
   print("This is invalid")
   c++
 elif guess.lower() > letter:
   print("This too high")
   c++
 elif guess.lower() < letter:
   print("this is too low")
   c++
 else:
   print("that is correct")
   c=4
 if c<=3
   check_guess()
```

Comment: this isn't valid python